# Regular Expression not matched

Tags: android, regex

I am trying to validate my string with the regular expression. Here is what I am trying to do

```
EditText serialText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pinText);
serialText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
serialNumber = serialText.getText().toString();
```

I am storing the serial number in serialNumber

I have the following method to match the regular expression

```
boolean isRegularSerialNumber(String pinNumber) {
  // regular expression to be matched against
  String regularString = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}";

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regularString);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(pinNumber);
  boolean isRegularSerialNumberValid ;

  if (pinNumber.matches(regularString)) 
    isRegularSerialNumberValid = true;
  else 
    isRegularSerialNumberValid = false;

  return isRegularSerialNumberValid;
}
```

But I am not able to match this.

Any answer for this? Hope Pattern and Matcher are the right one for this.

---

What I am trying to do is this, this matched serialNumber I am validating against serial number stored in the database. If match found, it returns success or else failure. And i have entered the exact serial number which is stored in the database but even then it returns failure.

I followed the method what @Stevehb said and i got the match true in that case.

This is how I am sending my data

parameter.add(new BasicNameValuePair("validate", serialNumber));

Breaking my head on this.

Comment: I don't think you need `Matcher` in `isRegularSerialNumber()`. You're not using it.

Comment: Do you think, this is causing the issue for me?

Comment: couldn't you just write your Pattern like this: `"([0-9]{4}){4}"`  ? just an optimization... 
then use your matcher, you have created like :
`if (matcher.matches()) { ... } else { ...}`

Comment: @Rafael T: `([0-9]{4}){4}` doesn't match the hyphens.

Comment: The Matcher object isn't getting used, but that's not why you're getting incorrect results.  I think the problem is with the input, as @stevehb said in his answer.

Comment: You can simplify your regex pattern to this (?:\d{4}-){3}\d{4} . Also, in your code just do a return pinNumber.matches(regularString) instead of saying isRegularSerialNumberValid = false ... isRegularSerialNumberValid = true...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The built in `String` functions should work by themselves. `isRegularSerialNumber()` could just be

```
boolean isRegularSerialNumber(String pinNumber) {
    String regularString = "[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}";
    return pinNumber.matches(regularString);
}
```

This works for me when I tested `1234-5678-9012-1324` (true) and `12-1234-123-1324` (false).

Also, it looks like you're maybe grabbing the input string from `serialText` right after you make it visible. Could your problem be in grabbing the text before the user has made any input?

Comment: +1. ...or maybe there are extra characters around the pin number.  For example, `isRegularSerialNumber("1234-5678-9012-3456")` is true, but `isRegularSerialNumber(" 1234-5678-9012-3456 ")` is false.

Comment: Or maybe the hyphens are being removed.  @thejaswi, are you examining the string that gets sent to that method?

Comment: @stevehb, I tried your method. It is returning true for me, but when I try to post the same serial Number with the Http Post it is giving me Invalid Serial Number. I have given the right serial number according to my requirement.

Comment: @Alan Moore, yes I was examining the string that gets sent to that method only. Now in that part I am able to do it

Comment: You should add anchors to the regex, like `^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{4}){3}$`, otherwise it will match 123456-1234-1234-123456 as well.  (Also refactored the regex to make it less repetitive; the main issue here is with the addition of the start of line marker `^` at the beginning and the end of line `$` at the end.)

Comment: @tripleee: Java's `matches()` method acts as if the anchors were there anyway, so that wouldn't make any difference.  Not that it's bad advice, but that's not the cause of the problem--or any potential problems--in this case.

Answer (score 1):

looks much alike .net regex code.

instead of

```
if (pinNumber.matches(regularString))
```

try

```
if (matcher.matches())
```